# How to link a Button Activity to another Textview Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to perform this in Android Studio with just 2 Activities.

I have an Activity having 3 Buttons, I have another Activity having 3 Textview,  when I click Button 1, it start Textview 1, when I click Button 2, it stills start from Textview 1, likewise Button 3.

But I need a code that will let me to locate each Textview according to each Buttons...  Remember I am having one Activity for 3 Buttons,  another Activity for 3 Textview,  so when I click on button 1, it should jumps to Textview 1,when I click on Button 2 it should jump to Textview 2, likewise Button 3.

I don't know if this is possible with just 2 Activities.

Expected solution: 
*Each Buttons should open Textview accordingly:

Food button should start view from I love eating beans
Animal button Should start view from I love puppy 
Hobby button should start view from I love soccer

My Button Activity Code:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/food"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Food"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/anima"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Animal"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hob"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Hobby"/>
```

My Textview Activity Code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fo"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="I love eating Beans"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/puppy"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="I love puppy"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/soc"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="I love Soccer"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your code - code speaks more than a thousand words.

Comment: First off, too confusing, too many words! Second, post your code and what didint work, and what you did to try to fix it. At StackOverFlow, we expect that you have tried to slove your problem first, then is you still cant find an answer post the code that didint work

Comment: Post have been Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Intent** to perform this task

```
Button food = (Button) findViewById(R.id.food);
food.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent foodIntent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
       foodIntent.putExtra("intent","foodButton");
       startActivity(foodIntent);
    }
});

Button anima = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anima);
anima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent animaIntent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
       animaIntent.putExtra("intent","animaButton");
       startActivity(animaIntent);
    }
});

Button hob = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hob);
hob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent hobIntent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
       hobIntent.putExtra("intent","hobButton");
       startActivity(hobIntent);
    }
});
```

In **OtherActivity.class** where you want to display the TextView

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            String newString= extras.getString("intent");
            switch(newString){
                case "foodButton":
                      fo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      puppy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      soc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      break;
                case "animaButton":
                      fo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      puppy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      soc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      break;
                case "hobButton":
                      fo.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
                      puppy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      soc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      break;
               }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply programmer @zilan,  I will give it a try and get back here!

Comment: Please where will I paste this code? I paste in Oncreate Bundle,  and got the error message  symbol can't found for;
                    fo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    puppy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    soc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: you declare and initialize the textViews with xml before working with the textView, thats the reason of error message

Comment: Let me try  it again, if I encounter error I will let you know, thanks!